# EPOCH Unix MYSQL Query

Tags: php, date

I'am using a script that saves some fields into my database as Epoch & Unix Timestamp format, (I think because the field is submitting as something like 1515469971), the column is an "int" format type.

I want to know, how I can make a query, to search all the inputs that have created on the current month.

I am so confused about it, hope you can help me :)

Comment: hint  `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, show me your table structure with `show create table table_name`.

If you're using an `int` to store the time. There are two ways to do that:

1. Convert the field to a date string with [from_unixtime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime). Then you got a string like '2018-01-08 05:05:05', and just compare the month value.
2. Calculate the very beginning and the end of the *current month* in advance. Then just `select * from table_name where time >= beginning_of_the_month and time <= end_of_the_month`.